# call function when div appears (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, events

I wonder if it's possible to write a function that calls when an element is created (or visible)?

For example:
1. When you click a button a div with id "area" gets created with DOM.
2. When a div with the id "area" exist, run function "areaFunction".

I have tried the code below, which doesn't work.

```
var App = {

    init: function () {
        if ($("#area") == true) {
            areaFunction();
        });
    },
}

window.onload = Capsule.init;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
if($('#area').length > 0){
    areaFunction();
});
```

Comment: This can also be shortened to `if ($('#area').length) {`

Answer (score 1):

if you write the function to create he div yourself you could do something like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var p = {
                createDivBtnOnclick: function() {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerHTML = "it's a div";
                    document.body.appendChild(div);
                areaFuntion();
                }
            };
            function areaFuntion() {
                alert("function areaFuntion() called");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Create Div" onclick="p.createDivBtnOnclick()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

if not you could work with a timer to check if the div exists. You could check as follows:

```
if(document.getElementById("divId") != null) { areaFunction() }
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing `==true`, use `if($("area").length > 0)`